# Doesn't show image type after upload in json response [Flutter Web]

Tags: flutter, postman

Recently in my Flutter web app project, i was need upload an image to the server and i had a lot of problem about it,so i finally found a way but it isn't showing the image type in JSON response after uploading the image on the server. however, I know uploading in the Backend side is correct, and also after uploading the image, shows on the server side correct but in JSON  response is not correct.

> if you look to the yellow side everything is correct that was uploaded by Postman.but
> if you look to the green side isn't correct that  that was uploaded by the Flutter web app.

[image: JSON Response | Flutter Web App]

My Flutter code
Image pick :

```
List<int>? _selectedFile;
  Uint8List? _bytesData;

  startWebFilePicker() async {
    FileUploadInputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
    uploadInput.multiple = true;
    uploadInput.draggable = false;
    uploadInput.click();

    uploadInput.onChange.listen((event) {
      final files = uploadInput.files;
      final file = files![0];
      final reader = FileReader();

      reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) {
        setState(() {
          _bytesData =
              Base64Decoder().convert(reader.result.toString().split(",").last);
          _selectedFile = _bytesData;
          print('_bytesData -> ${_bytesData}');
        });
      });
      reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
    });
  }
```

Upload on Server :

```
 Future uploadImage() async {
    String token = await apiController.getToken();
    var url = Uri.parse(conf.url);
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';

    request.fields['name'] = 'parent cat';
    request.fields['description'] = 'description cat';
    request.fields['parent_id'] = '';
    request.fields['is_active'] = '1';
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'image', _selectedFile!,
        contentType: new MediaType('*', '*'), filename: "image"));

    request.send().then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('response.statusCode -> ${response.stream}');
        print("File uploaded successfully");
      } else {
        print('file upload failed');
      }
    });
  }
```

Log cat response for me after upload  ->
File uploaded successfully

I don't know what to do because everything is correct and I get the correct response from the server, but the photo is without an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload image with their name along with their extensions.
For ex. image1.jpg, image2.jpg

```
Future uploadImage() async {
    String token = await apiController.getToken();
    var url = Uri.parse(conf.url);
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';

    request.fields['name'] = 'category name'; 

    request.fields['description'] = 'description cat';
    request.fields['parent_id'] = '';
    request.fields['is_active'] = '1';
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'image', _selectedFile!,
        contentType: new MediaType('*', '*'), filename: "image.jpg"))//Add your file name here;

    request.send().then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('response.statusCode -> ${response.stream}');
        print("File uploaded successfully");
      } else {
        print('file upload failed');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: **request.fields['name'] = 'parent_image.jpg'; //Add your file name here** this field about my category name and is not for image name

Comment: check now , i've updated my answer.     

filename: "image.jpg"